# JavaScript Object Manipulation Questions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

At the moment I am working on an ionic app (angular1) and I am working on a huge object.

The Object will look like this:

```
userWorkouts: [
  {
    title: '3 Split',
    id: 1,
    workoutImg: '',
    workoutSessions: {
      1: {
        workoutSessionName: 'Monday',
        workoutExerciseList: {
          1: {
            exerciseName: "Pull Ups",
            exerciseSets: {
              1: 20,
              2: 12,
              3: 8
            }
          },
          2: {
            exerciseName: "Pull Ups",
            exerciseSets: {
              1: 20,
              2: 12,
              3: 8
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    title: 'Kraftausdauer Teil 1',
    id: 2,
    workoutImg: ''
  },
  {
    title: 'Kraftausdauer Teil 2',
    id: 3,
    workoutImg: ''
  },
  {
    title: '7 Minuten Training',
    id: 4,
    workoutImg: ''
  },
  {
    title: 'Workout Zuhause',
    id: 5,
    workoutImg: ''
  }
]
```

For Example: A User have x Workouts. Each Workout have x Sessions (Monday, Wednesday, Friday). A session have also x Exercises with x sets.

The Problem: I want to modify this object and I have a few problems:

Problem: I want to add Sessions (Monday, Wednesday, Friday).

```
var session = {
        workoutSessionName: sessionName
      };

userWorkouts[1].push(session)
```

Doesn't work, because its an object. Is there another way to "push" to an object?

Comment: Is there a Problem 2 or is that a mistake?

Comment: why do you have objects with incrementing integers as the keys? Why not use arrays?

Comment: Agreed. `workoutSessions`, `workoutExerciseList` and `exerciseSets` should all be defined as arrays of objects, not objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if i understood try to change to this.

```
userWorkouts: [
  {
    title: '3 Split',
    id: 1,
    workoutImg: '',
    workoutSessions: [{
     {
        workoutSessionName: 'Monday',
        workoutExerciseList: [{
          1: {
            exerciseName: "Pull Ups",
            exerciseSets: {
              1: 20,
              2: 12,
              3: 8
            }
          },
          2: {
            exerciseName: "Pull Ups",
            exerciseSets: {
              1: 20,
              2: 12,
              3: 8
            }
          }
        }
      }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    title: 'Kraftausdauer Teil 1',
    id: 2,
    workoutImg: ''
  },
  {
    title: 'Kraftausdauer Teil 2',
    id: 3,
    workoutImg: ''
  },
  {
    title: '7 Minuten Training',
    id: 4,
    workoutImg: ''
  },
  {
    title: 'Workout Zuhause',
    id: 5,
    workoutImg: ''
  }
]
```

and use like this

```
var session = {
        workoutSessionName: sessionName
      };

userWorkouts[1].workoutSessions.push(session)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure you need to use 1. array or 2. object for `workoutSessions`

1. You could use array to hold `workoutSessions` instead of object because you are already using an integer as a key and then just add using `push()`
2. Check `angular.extend` https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.extend

Here is a plunk for option 2:
https://plnkr.co/edit/x0isJdzXHq2gX7vfsQdG?p=preview